# Saída em duas colunas

Tags: python-3.x

A saída do meu código faz uma lista em uma coluna.

Código:

```
path = '/home/allan/Área de trabalho/adjetivos.txt'
i = 0
lista = []
conta = 1
with open (path) as file_obj:
    ler = file_obj.readlines()
for le in ler:

    #print(le.rstrip())
    lista.append(le)

for i in lista:
    tam = len(lista)
    #print(tam)
    if i == lista[0]:
        print("1 ano: Bodas de "+str(i.title().rstrip()))
    elif i != lista[0]:
        conta = 1 + conta
        print(str(conta)+" anos: Bodas de "+i.title().rstrip())
```

Saída atual:

```
1 ano: Bodas de Ágata
2 anos: Bodas de Água-Marinha
3 anos: Bodas de Âmbar
4 anos: Bodas de Alabastro
5 anos: Bodas de Alexandrita
6 anos: Bodas de Amazônia
7 anos: Bodas de Ametista
8 anos: Bodas de Andaluzite
9 anos: Bodas de Aventurina
10 anos: Bodas de Axinite
...
```

...Assim continua

Gostaria de "quebrar o texto", que a lista continuasse ao lado como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer?

---

```
for texto in textos:
    print(max(len(texto)))
```

Porque não consigo ter o mesmo efeito de contar os caracteres como vc fez usando listcomp? Minha interpretação vendo o código trabalhando em pythontutor é de 2 itens da lista formarem 1,  Ex: "café","açucar" --> "café         açucar". Parece mágica, como ele consegue se incluir?

Aqui:
É assim que acontece? Veja a seguir:
 `escritas[pos % linhas_coluna]` seria como isso:

```
...
[3 % 25]
[4 % 25]
[5 % 25]
...
```

Assim sendo pegaria o `3`  e atribuiria a `anos: Bodas de Âmbar (espaço de 25)`

`texto.ljust(tamanho, ' ')` seria:

`anos: Bodas de Âmbar (espaço de 25)` ,certo? 
 Eu não consigo ver este texto indo para a direita, apenas para ljust(esquerda) assim formando uma coluna só!

Lembrando: O programa está trabalhando perfeitamente bem, mas eu não alcanço a lógica em si. Como ele consegue se dividir em dois se tudo vai para a esquerda??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu começaria por simplificar e tornar o código mais Pythonico antes sequer de partir para a quebra em colunas.

Para isso pode utilizar [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para a construção da lista de adjetivos, assim como `enumerate` para não ter que construir as posições manualmente:

```
path = '/home/allan/Área de trabalho/adjetivos.txt'
with open (path) as file_obj:
    ler = file_obj.readlines()

lista = [le.strip() for le in ler] #strip apenas na passagem para a lista
for pos,adjetivo in enumerate(lista):
    print("{} ano{}: Bodas de {}".format(pos+1, "" if pos == 0 else "s", adjetivo.title()))
```

Para quebrar em colunas pode criar uma nova lista com os textos que seriam escritos ao invés de apenas os adjetivos que vieram do arquivo. Depois cria outra lista que corresponde às linhas das colunas, e passa cada texto para a linha correspondente.

Para organizar e estruturar pode criar uma função que faça isso:

```
from math import ceil

def escrita_colunas(textos, colunas):
    linhas_coluna = ceil(len(textos) / colunas)
    tamanho = max([len(texto) for texto in textos]) + 1 #+1 para criar espaço entre colunas
    escritas = [''] * linhas_coluna

    for pos, texto in enumerate(textos):
        escritas[pos % linhas_coluna] += texto.ljust(tamanho, ' ')

    for escrita in escritas:
        print(escrita)
```

Utilizei o [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust) para alinhar cada texto à esquerda baseado no maior `tamanho` dos vários textos a serem escritos, o que vai permitir criar o alinhamento visual.

Para colocar o texto na linha certa utilizei o operador modulo `%`. Para percebermos melhor como este operador funciona podemos começar por considerar o seguinte código:

```
for i in range(15):
    print(i % 5)
```

Que produz o seguinte resultado:

```
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
```

[Veja você mesmo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/PU0AcC)

Aqui vemos ao fazermos `% 5` o numero será sempre entre `0` e `4` e de forma circular. Aplicando ao seu exemplo de 50 textos e 2 colunas irá dar `pos % 25` que lhe dará um numero sempre entre 0 e 24. Será 0 a 24 para a primeira coluna e depois novamente 0 a 24 para a segunda coluna.

Posto isto, basta construir os textos a serem escritos e chamar a função:

```
path = '/home/allan/Área de trabalho/adjetivos.txt'
with open (path) as file_obj:
    ler = file_obj.readlines()

lista = [le.strip() for le in ler]
textos = []
for pos,adjetivo in enumerate(lista):
    textos.append("{} ano{}: Bodas de {}".format(pos+1,"" if pos == 0 else "s",adjetivo.title()))

escrita_colunas(textos, 2)
```

[Veja a função de escrita em colunas a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/HalTLF)

**Edit**:

Tendo em conta que a função que fiz de escritas em colunas não ficou clara para si decidi refaze-la sendo o mais manual possível não utilizando nenhuma função nativa, para ver todo o processo:

```
def escrita_colunas(textos, colunas):
    linhas_coluna = ceil(len(textos) / colunas)

    tamanho_max = 0 
    for texto in textos: #achar o tamanho do maior texto entre todos os textos
        tamanho = len(texto) + 1 #+1 para dar espaço entre colunas
        if tamanho > tamanho_max:
            tamanho_max = tamanho

    escritas = [''] * linhas_coluna #criar as colunas

    linha = 0 
    for texto in textos:
        #se chegou ao limite de linhas desta coluna volta a 0 para
        #"passar para a próxima coluna"
        if linha == linhas_coluna:
            linha = 0

        #quantos carateres faltam para chegar a quantidade de carateres da coluna
        carateres_faltam = tamanho_max - len(texto) 

        #colocar os carateres que faltam como espaços a seguir ao texto
        texto_inserir = texto + (' ' * carateres_faltam)

        escritas[linha] = escritas[linha] + texto_inserir
        linha = linha + 1

    for escrita in escritas:
        print(escrita)
```

[Veja também esta versão no Ideone a funcionar](https://ideone.com/lZFlTd#stdin)

Comment: Apontei 3 dúvidas. Aceitei mas não entendi porque a string 'tamanho' retorna 43.
`tamanho = max([len(texto) for texto in textos]) + 1`

Aqui onde não entendi mais:
`for pos, texto in enumerate(textos):
        escritas[pos % linhas_coluna] += texto.ljust(tamanho, ' ')`

Minha interpretação:

escritas[De 0 a 49 % 25 ] <-- Não entendi, 50 % 25 = 0


=+ <-- Acrescentará aonde? 


texto.ljust(43, ' ') ##texto com 43 espaços justificado a esquerda , um espaço vazio ' '. <-- Além do tamanho ser 43 não entendi o vazio.

Comment: @AllanBelem tamanho devolve `43` porque considera os textos já construídos como "1 ano: Bodas de Ágata" ao invés de apenas os adjetivos. Em `+= texto.ljust(tamanho, ' ')` estamos a acrescentar o texto corrente alinhado à esquerda com tamanho `43`, e se tiver menos acrescenta espaços à direita até fazer `43`. Em `escritas[pos % linhas_coluna]` acontece que para `50` elementos e `2` colunas irá dar `pos % 25` que será um numero entre `0` e `24` sempre. É uma forma de garantir que não passa dos `24` e volta sempre a 0 sendo circular. Se vir o histórico de edições vê outra forma de fazer o mesmo

Comment: @Allan Se quiser ficar ainda mais consciente de como o operador modulo funciona nesse caso, observe o código e a saída [deste programa](https://ideone.com/PU0AcC). Outra coisa que seria interessante é visualizar o código na minha resposta no [visualizador online de python](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html) que é bastante intuitivo e lhe dá uma noção muito visual do que está a acontecer

Comment: Estou estudando seu código, ainda me encontro confuso, gostaria de saber outra coisa a respeito do formato do seu código, a forma como ele é descrito resume as funções numa linha só, existe um nome técnico para esta representação? Quero aprender desta forma, já que os livros avançados/intermediários ensinam da forma que você apresentou.

Comment: @AllanBelem Se se está a referir a algo como `lista = [le.strip() for le in ler]` então sim, chama-se [*List Comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Aconselho assim ler esse artigo da documentação para ficar mais familiarizado de como funciona. A ideia principal no entanto tornar o código mais curto, simples  e legível

Comment: @AllanBelem Re-editei a minha resposta colocando uma função de escrita em colunas totalmente manual, para ser o mais simples possível sem utilizar funções nativas. Veja se consegue perceber o código e se faz sentido, de preferência vendo no pythontutor também. Se ficar com questões não hesite em colocar.